# No Bootable Device Error after keyboard replacement

Tags: laptop, ssd, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire S7 and recently replaced a faulty keyboard. During the replacement, I stupidly did not disconnect the battery and may have corrupted something in the process.

After the replacement, when I boot up the computer I get a `no available boot device` error. There also are no drives found in the BIOS. If I hit F2 during boot, it has no effect and takes me to the same screen. If I completely remove the SSD and boot, I get the same behavior.

Since these SSD's seem to be hot-swappable, I don't think I "wiped" the drive during disassembly, but I'm not sure. Maybe I damaged the connection some other way?

It may not be relevant, but the the battery doesn't seem to hold a charge very well and it doesn't register as charging when the power adapter is plugged in.

Everything inside seems plugged in properly.

What might I have done during the repair that corrupted the drive? What troubleshooting steps should I take to work towards a successful boot with the drive?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2odzL.jpg]

Comment: Try to remove the battery and press the power button about 30 seconds. It will clear your bios. Also, if you have another computer, try to connect your SSD in another pc. If nothing of this helps you, maybe your motherboard "died".

Comment: Thanks for the info.  However the button push didn't do the trick.  Is it common for motherboards to 'die' just like that?  Are there other things I can try to determine if the motherboard is still functioning.  For instance - the fans work fine - does that say anything?

Comment: Try to connect into a external monitor (HDMI or VGA). If you touch the motherboard until the battery still connected, you probably will "burn" some components....